# php to html request without changing browser url

Tags: php

My site is working with .html extension in the URL. However i want to change it to .php. But pages are not working. Is there any way that url is using .php extension and server is treating it as .html request

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don’t have Apache setup to parse PHP files. Unless I am missing what the question is? You want too rename the `.html` files to `.php` and still have them work?

By default in Ubuntu 12.04 PHP is enabled via the `php5.conf` file in `mods-available` that should look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```